# Angular2 bind array with ngFor

Tags: angular

I am using angular2 and in my forms I usually create a model class and bind my object with the form then access is via this.myObject.

```
<div class="form-group ">
 <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Label</label>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="diplome.label" name="label">
 </div>
</div>
```

And get my data later

```
private diplome = new Diplome();
let myData = this.diplome;
```

---

I am now on a position when I show an array of data using `*ngFor`, and I want when clicking on submit to get all of them as an array of a specific class.

```
...
<tr *ngFor="let inscription of inscriptions">
 <td>
   <span *ngIf="inscription._etudiant">{{ inscription._etudiant.label }}</span>
 </td>
 <td>
  <div class="form-group ">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <input type="number" class="form-control" name="note">
    </div>
  </div>
 </td>
</tr>
...
```

I want to be able to get in every iteration the inscription object with the data being inserted into the input using binding.

Comment: exactly where do you want to get it?

Comment: Inside my component.ts after firing submit click button.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [FormArray](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html) class to bind your inputs to an array. I wrote out a quick demo for you below. It's better to use FormBuilder to set up your forms as you can bind Validators to your FormControls, and you can simply get the model object with `FormGroup.value`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'ExampleForm',
  template: `<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
               <div formArrayName="formArray">
                 <div *ngFor="let control of formGroup.controls.formArray.controls; let i=index">
                   <input type="text" formControlName="{{i}}">
                 </div>
               </div>
               <button (click)="addInput()">Add Input</button>
             </form>
             <pre>{{formGroup.value | json}}</pre> `
})
export class ExampleForm {
  private formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      formArray: this.fb.array([
        this.fb.control('')
      ])
    });
  }

  addInput() {
    this.formGroup.controls.formArray.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }
}
```

Comment: When I do that, the typescript compiler says `Property formArray does not exist on type ...`. Does this really work for you? I can run the code, and when I console.log the `this.formGroup` I get the object containing `formArray` as this is correct at runtime. How to solve that?