# Dynamically adding/removing controls to Angular2 form

Tags: forms, angular, typescript

I have an angular2-final form with a variable number of checkbox inputs using the *ngFor directive.  This seems to work fine, as long as the number of checkboxes is set once in ngOnInit.  However, I need to be able to add/remove checkboxes dynamically and I'm not sure how to do that.

What component logic is necessary to make it so that the inputs can be added/removed from a model-driven form, like the one below, on the fly?

Example form code:

```
<form [formGroup]="editProjectForm" (ngSubmit)="edit()" *ngIf="!isLoading">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="hero-form-label" for="name">Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" formControlName="name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="hero-form-label" for="description">Description</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" formControlName="description">
  </div>

  <label class="hero-form-label">Members</label>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead class="thead-default">
    <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email Address</th>
    <th>Include</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody *ngIf="project?.members === 0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">This project has no members.</td>
  </tr>  
</tbody>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let user of users">
    <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
    <td>{{user.email}}</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="{{user.id}}" value="{{user.id}}" value="{{ project.hasUser(user.id) }}">
      </td>
    </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your template I'm not sure where you are adding a variable number of checkboxes, unless you are referring to your `users` loop.

To answer your exact question:

> What component logic is necessary to make it so that the inputs can be
>   added/removed from a model-driven form?

What you'll need is the [FormArray](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html) class. It can contain a variable number of controls, which should be able to solve your use case. You can use an `*ngFor` with a FormArray.

Your model driven form could look something like this:

```
editProjectForm = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(''),
  description: new FormControl(''),
  users: new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl(''),
      lastName: new FormControl(''),
      email: new FormControl(''),
      options: new FormArray([
        new FormGroup({
          type: new FormControl('Project Has User'),
          value: new FormControl(false)
        })
      ])
    })
  ])
});
```

And [Angular2 bind array with ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855200/angular2-bind-array-with-ngfor) has an example of binding to FormArray.

Comment: Was able to implement. Works great.